# Upgrade Sonar from 4.5.4 to 5.1 is failing with Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migratio ns.v50.FeedFileSources

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

We are having issues upgrading our Sonar DB.  Along with this generic message we are also seeing Caused by:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.file_sources' with unique index 'file_sources_file_uuid_uniq'. The duplicate key value is etc...

How can we identify what needs to be cleaned up to proceed forward?

The [full log](http://pastebin.ca/3002264) is posted on pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Delete the unique index **file_sources_file_uuid_uniq** on the table **file_sources**. When Sonarqube is creating a complete new database the index will not be created. It seems the migration scripts missed to delete the index.